# Exchange server 2010 receiver connector configuration to send alert email without authentication

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, smtp-auth

I have an application which sends email using java mail library. It works perfectly fine in all my customer environments except one. I believe there is some problem with the receiver connector for exchange server in the environment. I only have following stack for the java mail failure. Could you please suggest any possible change to connector

```
 EHLO localhost
 250-atprelaytest.xng2k10win2k8r2.com Hello [10.219.170.45]
 250-SIZE 10485760
 250-PIPELINING
 250-DSN
 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 250-AUTH
 250-8BITMIME
 250-BINARYMIME
 250-CHUNKING
 250-XEXCH50
 250 XSHADOW
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST- MD5 NTLM
 DEBUG SMTP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
 DEBUG SMTP: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
 DEBUG SMTP: mechanism DIGEST-MD5 not supported by server
 DEBUG SMTP: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
 ERROR EmailSender - Error in sending email : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
```

org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to connect using SSL before the server will let you authenticate.